# Value initialization of statically allocated object

Tags: c++, initialization

I have such class:

```
class Car {
    int x;
public:
    Car() {cout << "Init car" << endl;}
    Car(const Car & c) { cout << "Copy car" << endl;}
    Car(const Car && c) { cout << "Move car" << endl;}
};
```

When I want to value-initalize an object of class `Car`:

```
Car c = Car();
```

Only the default constructor is called. Why copy construcotr or move constructor is not called since there is an assignement?

Comment: No copy or move constructor is called because nothing is being copied or moved.

Comment: There is no assignment. `T x = T();` is an initialization, and since C++17 there is not even a temporary being created here. The standard has an example showing exactly that: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1.example-1

Comment: @michalt38 No, that is incorrect. It may look like an assignment and a temporary, but that's not how C++ works. `T x = ...;` has never involved an assignment - it is an initialization, and works differently from `T x; x = ...;`. Yes, that can be surprising/confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is guaranteed from C++17.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The
>   objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would
>   otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be
>   present or accessible:
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is
>     a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the
>     variable type:
>
>   ```
>   T f() {
>       return T();
>   }
>
>   T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
>   ```

PS: `T x = T();` is not assignment but initialization, more precisely it's [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).